# Rename columns without losing values R

Tags: r

I have a dataset in which the column names are actually data points.  I am unable to use the modifications available in the `read` functions, because the data is already loaded into the session.  If I rename the column, I lose the values in the first row, which is not acceptable.  How do I shift those values down and add the headers?

```
# Data looks like this
blue <- c('yellow', 'red', 'green')
primary <- c('primary', 'primary', 'secondary')
have <- data.frame(blue, primary)

# I can rename columns but I'll lose that row of data
colnames(have) <- c('color', 'type')

# This is what I want
color <- c('blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'green')
type <- c('primary', 'primary', 'primary', 'secondary')
want <- data.frame(color, type)
```

Comment: `blue <- c('yellow', 'red', 'green')` — and you think that variable name is OK? 

Comment: you must not have read the question....  ;)

Comment: I read it. My question is, why/how do you have such a structure in the first place? Your question is addressing the symptom rather than the cause.

Comment: Yes...yes it is.  But I didn't ask for a solution to the problem of the client's data structure.  That is something I can solve later.  For now, I need to know how to rename the column and preserve the values that have been stored there...which is why I asked this question.

Comment: An easy way using the `read` functions would be simply to write the data to disk and read it in again using appropriate arguments.

Comment:  My comment was a roundabout way of saying that you have an [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/1968), and that a *good* solution will involve you rethinking your problem statement. Next time I’ll try it without veiled attempts at humour.

Comment: Thought about that, but transferring the data out/back into the environment is too costly.

Comment: @KonradRudolph no worries, i completely agree this is a problem.  Unfortunately, I am working with a limited time frame and access to their data for a POC type situation...so I just need a band-aid for now.

Comment: As @KonradRudolph said, you probably need to rethink your problem. For example you could try reading your data with the `header = FALSE` parameter in the `read.*`-function you are using.

Comment: I have already stated that I am not using a `read` function.  The data is already in an environment and has been provided for me.  I cannot change the way the data has been read in.  I will absolutely make the recommendation post-project that the client reconsider how data is uploaded.  But for now, I simply need to name the columns and move the data there into a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way.
First, your data before changing its names.

```
blue <- c('yellow', 'red', 'green')
primary <- c('primary', 'primary', 'secondary')
have <- data.frame(blue, primary)
```

Now the code.

```
want2 <- have
want2[] <- lapply(have, as.character)
want2 <- rbind(names(want2), want2)
names(want2) <- c('color', 'type')
want2
#   color      type
#1   blue   primary
#2 yellow   primary
#3    red   primary
#4  green secondary
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works for my use case.  I changed `want2` to `have` to avoid writing the data again due to size.

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy the dataframe header to a new line:

```
have[,1] = factor(have[,1],levels = c("blue","yellow","red","green")) #This is to define that "blue" is a factor
have[4,] = colnames(have) # Adds the table header to line 4
colnames(have) <- c('color', 'type') # redefine header
```

Comment: My actual datasets are millions of rows and 100 columns wide.  Don't think refactoring to include the new value is an option....otherwise this approach could work.